# Migration from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012 - Stored Procedure issue

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm migrating to SQL server 2012 and after attaching the database to SQL server 2012, I found that I have a lot of stored procedures that building query using concatenate text.
How could I validate the script that written in this way?
And how could I make sure that proc's syntax valid?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will have to execute each of them and make sure they work. Even normal stored procedures can break after migrating to SQL Server 2012, in particular if they use OPENROWSET or OPENQUERY.